# How to change both points and path sizes in qplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars,geom='point',size=I(0.8))` can change the points size.

But how to change both path and points size in qplot()?

I've tried

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars,geom=c('point','path'),size=I(0.8,0.8))
```

and

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars,geom=c('point','path'),size=c(I(0.8),I(0,8))
```

and

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars,geom=c('point','path'),size=I(c(0.8,0.8)))
```

None of them works.

Comment: I'd say: use `ggplot` instead of `qplot`.

Comment: Something like: `ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(size = 0.8) + geom_path(size = 0.8)`